# BadRequestKeyError(key) werkzeug.exceptions. 400 The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'name'

Tags: python, flask

I've a problem with sending from a html form to a python flask application.

First the html code:

```
           <form id="signup-form" class="bg-white rounded"
                  autocomplete="no" id="signup-form" action="/signup" method="post">
                <h2 class="mt-0 mb-0 text-center">Sign Up For</h2>
                <h2 class="mb-4 mt-0 text-center">Free Trial</h2>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control mb-2" id="fieldForName" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="new-name" required>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control mb-2" id="fieldForEmail" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="new-email" required>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control mb-2" id="fieldForPassword" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-pass" required>
                <div id="output" class="pb-2 row align-items-center justify-content-center text-danger font-weight-bold">{{ message }}</div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" autocomplete="new-submit">
                  <div id="register-text">Register</div>
                  {% include 'partials/spinner.html' %}
                </button>
                
            </form>
```

Second the python code:

```
@user_api.route("/signup", methods=["POST"])
def signup():

    print("RequestForm: " + str(request.form))

    name = str(request.form["name"])
    mail = str(request.form["email"])
    password = str(request.form["password"])

    json_request = jsonify(
        name=name,
        email=mail,
        password=password
    )

    action.signup(json_request)

    return redirect("/login_page", code=302)
```

Third the error message:

```
RequestForm: ImmutableMultiDict([])
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2022 14:37:46] "POST /signup HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/robertgroll/VSCRepos/landingpage/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/robertgroll/VSCRepos/landingpage/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/robertgroll/VSCRepos/landingpage/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/robertgroll/VSCRepos/landingpage/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/robertgroll/VSCRepos/landingpage/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/robertgroll/VSCRepos/landingpage/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/robertgroll/VSCRepos/landingpage/app/Service/service_calls/call_user_service.py", line 24, in signup
    name = str(request.form["name"])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/robertgroll/VSCRepos/landingpage/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 375, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'name'
```

Can you please help me by giving me at least a hint.
Thank you!

I've tried to rename name of the input fields and I've done some reorganizing of the html.
Now I want to get the submit values inside the dictionary to have the right data in the post html call.

Answer (score 0):

!!!!Solved!!!!

The overgiven post message is a json-string. So I have handle it like this.

```
def signup(self, request):
    # Get data from AJAX request
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    
    email = data['email']
    password = data['password']
    name = data['name']

    message, status_code = db_access.create_user(email=email,
                                                password=password,
                                                name=name)

    return message, status_code
```

Thank you again.